# Will GKE cluster will have downtime, when cluster features are enabled/disable?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, outage

I wanted to enable cloud operations for a zonal GKE cluster with just one node. I read lots of guides from Google, but didn't found any mentioning about outage if we disable/enable cluster features. The guides just contains how to enable/disable features. Does anyone knows something about this topic?

Answer (score 0):

In case of multi-zonal clusters, during an upgrade of the cluster or an outage of the zone where the control plane runs, workloads still run. However, the cluster, its nodes, and its workloads cannot be configured until the control plane is available. Multi-zonal clusters balance availability and cost for consistent workloads. If you want to maintain availability and the number of your nodes and node pools are changing frequently, consider using a [regional cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/types-of-clusters#regional_clusters).

For more information on upgrading your clusters with zero downtime refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-upgrading-your-clusters-with-zero-downtime).